# Which value does EDX have after logic NEG and AND instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm solving one of the assembler questions and I stumbled upon one with logic aspect.
The thing that makes me thinking is that after changing the numeral system from HEX to BIN and making a negation and AND operations I got a different answer than other person (which I cannot contact).

```
MOV eax, 0f0f0f0f0h;
MOV edx, 87654321h;
NOT ax;
INC dx;
AND edx, eax;
```

I was expecting an output to be like this: 80604020h which is one of the answers, but the other person made a decision and answered: 80600302h which for me doesn't make a sense after doing the math. I'm still new in assembly so I may not know what is wrong, can someone explain what is wrong with my answer, or is it a correct one?

Comment: `80600302h` looks correct to me. You appear to have ignored the `NOT ax` instruction in your calculations.

Comment: Those leading zeros can be tricky.

Comment: Yea, they can be but I was having in mind doing NOT ax, but now I'm aware I was doing NOT to the whole EAX, not AX!

Answer (score 2):

Let's take this one instruction at a time.  The `NOT ax` will change EAX from

```
0F0F0F0F0
```

to

```
0F0F00F0F
```

since AX is the lower 16 bits of EAX.  Then the `INC dx` will change EDX from

```
 87654321
```

to

```
 87654322
```

The `AND edx,eax` instruction will then combine them

```
 0F0F00F0F
& 87654322
= 80600302
```

Which makes your friend's answer correct.

If the NOT instruction was `NOT EAX`, then the answer would be 07050302.

Comment: But what exactly happens at NOT ax statement? Why is the 4th "F" from the back shifting rest of the numbers to the right?

Comment: They aren't being shifted to the right, it's flipping all the bits. Those that are 1 will become 0 and the ones that were 0 will become 1.

Comment: @MariuszJędrzejewski `NOT AX` will only change the lower 16 bits of the EAX register.  The NOT instruction will flip all the bits of its operand.  In this case it is similar to `XOR EAX,0000FFFF`.  So the upper 4 nybbles are unchanged, and the lower 4 nybbles appear to shift but that's just because of the F0F0 pattern.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense!
We never really used or discussed AX (16bit) on our laboratories, so it explains a lot!